# IndexSettings Analysis of ElasticSearch Nest is null. How to add custom Analyzer?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I created my custom Analyzer which called "mynGram". But I can't add it to Analysis because of null. What is the right way to create Index with custom analyzer?

```
const string indexName = "taskmanager";
            ConnectionSettings settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200")).DefaultIndex("taskmanager").DefaultTypeNameInferrer(t => "tasks");
            elasticClient = new ElasticClient(settings);

            IndexSettings indexSettings = new IndexSettings();

            CustomAnalyzer customAnalyzer = new CustomAnalyzer();
            customAnalyzer.CharFilter = new List<string>();
            customAnalyzer.Tokenizer = "mynGram";
            customAnalyzer.Filter = new List<string> { "lowercase" };

            // test
            // Analysis is null
            indexSettings.Analysis = new Analysis();

            // Analyzers is null
            indexSettings.Analysis.Analyzers.Add("mynGram", customAnalyzer);
            indexSettings.Analysis.Tokenizers.Add("mynGram", new NGramTokenizer { MaxGram = 10, MinGram = 2 });

            IndexState indexConfig = new IndexState
            {
                Settings = indexSettings
            };

            elasticClient.CreateIndex(indexName, i => i
                .InitializeUsing(indexConfig)
            );
```

And before that I set this custom analyzer to Analyzer attribute.

```
[Text(Name = "Title", Index = false, Store = true, Analyzer = "mynGram")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
```

Comment: what version of NEST?

Answer (score 0):

Using the Object Initializer Syntax as you are, it would be in NEST 2.x and 5.x

```
var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
var defaultIndex = "taskmanager";
var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
        .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex);

var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

var customAnalyzer = new CustomAnalyzer
{
    Tokenizer = "mynGram",
    Filter = new[] { "lowercase" }
};

var createIndexRequest = new CreateIndexRequest(defaultIndex)
{
    Settings = new IndexSettings
    {
        Analysis = new Analysis
        {
            Analyzers = new Analyzers{ { "mynGram", customAnalyzer } },
            Tokenizers = new Tokenizers{ { "mynGram", new NGramTokenizer { MaxGram = 10, MinGram = 2 } } }
        }
    }
};

client.CreateIndex(createIndexRequest);
```